# HTTP authentication works in firefox but not on google chrome

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, google-chrome

I have a website who use an http authentication with a .htaccess 
This work perfect in Firefox, but it don't work with Chrome with the correct password.

The .htaccess code

```
AuthUserFile /web/posefauxcils/revuedigitale/htpasswd.txt
AuthName "Acces protege"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

The password in the htpasswd.txt is crypted with

```
crypt($_POST['pass'], '4kp')
```

Comment: "doesnt work" doesnt help, what exactly is, and is not happening?

Comment: The browser ask for user and password to access to website. With firefox, no problem, I enter the website. With google chrome, i put the correct user and password, but it ask again for credentials.

Comment: I tried to put the crypted password but no changes

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your file htpasswd.txt to .htpasswd

The .htaccess should contain :

```
AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/home/site/www/admin/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

And then in the .htpasswd :

```
login:crypted_passord
```

To see you crypted password:

```
<?php echo crypt('yourpass'); ?>
```

Comment: I tried to change the filename and the .htaccess but no changes :/